# Use server-slide JavaScript to transform search snippet in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, search, marklogic

My goal is to use server-side JavaScript to create my custom snippeter. Below is my minimal snippeter function (/snippets/transform-results.sjs):

```
const transform = (result, ctsquery, options) => {
  return result
}

module.exports = { transform }
```

and in search options:

```
<transform-results apply="transform" ns="" at="/snippets/transform-results.sjs"/>
```

However, I got the following error message:

> XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) let $snippet-func as function(*)? := if (fn:empty($options)) then () else map:get($resultdef, \"snippetFunc\") -- Invalid coercion: xdmp:function(fn:QName(\"\",\"transform\"), \"/snippets/transform-results.sjs\") as function(*) . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.

Comment: I am afraid that transform-results is one of the rare places that does not support server-side javascript. I suggest using a REST Transform instead, which can be applied on `/v1/search` results as well, and does support server-side javascript. It also allows handling all results in one go, and doing things beyond snippeting.

Comment: @grtjn But the `v1/search` is a pretty slow function - as I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77864084/how-do-i-fix-a-slow-search-function

Comment: @happybuddha, v1 search nor the underlying search.search are slow in itself. The cts.highlight that is used under the covers for snippeting however is, particularly for bigger documents.