# How do I fix a slow search function?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am looking into the search functionality of a Vue application built off of Grove-Vue. This application uses MarkLogic's REST API [v1/search](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search)

The search result for a two word search (from about 2 million documents, and about 10 different collections) takes 14 seconds to execute. 28 seconds if the pageLength is set to 20 and 42 seconds for thirty records.

To isolate the problem, when I search for the same 2 words using `search.search` function from [MarkLogic](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/search.search) in the query console, it takes about the  same time.

```
const search = require('/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search');
search.search("one two");
```

Which eliminates the delay from the UI layer. There is negligible difference with or without options - so options are not a problem either.

I looked at the [query tuning documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/performance/query_meters) and added `query-meters` to the `search.search` function. I see this :

```
"elapsedTime": "PT14.190265S", 
"requests": 0, 
"listCacheHits": 53, 
"listCacheMisses": 18, 
"listSize": 73324, 
"inMemoryListHits": 0, 
"tripleCacheHits": 0, 
"tripleCacheMisses": 0, 
"tripleValueCacheHits": 0, 
"tripleValueCacheMisses": 0, 
"expandedTreeCacheHits": 19, 
"expandedTreeCacheMisses": 0, 
"compressedTreeCacheHits": 0, 
"compressedTreeCacheMisses": 0, 
"compressedTreeSize": 0, 
"inMemoryCompressedTreeHits": 0, 
"valueCacheHits": 35, 
"valueCacheMisses": 35, 
"regexpCacheHits": 23, 
"regexpCacheMisses": 8, 
"linkCacheHits": 0, 
"linkCacheMisses": 0, 
"filterHits": 19, 
"filterMisses": 0, 
"fragmentsAdded": 0, 
"fragmentsDeleted": 0, 
"fsProgramCacheHits": 0, 
"fsProgramCacheMisses": 0, 
"dbProgramCacheHits": 0, 
"dbProgramCacheMisses": 0, 
"envProgramCacheHits": 0, 
"envProgramCacheMisses": 0, 
"fsMainModuleSequenceCacheHits": 0, 
"fsMainModuleSequenceCacheMisses": 0, 
"dbMainModuleSequenceCacheHits": 0, 
"dbMainModuleSequenceCacheMisses": 0, 
"fsLibraryModuleCacheHits": 0, 
"fsLibraryModuleCacheMisses": 25, 
"dbLibraryModuleCacheHits": 0, 
"dbLibraryModuleCacheMisses": 2, 
"readLocks": 0, 
"writeLocks": 0, 
"lockTime": 0, 
"contemporaneousTimestampTime": 0, 
"compileTime": 0.210152, 
"commitTime": 0, 
"runTime": 0, 
"indexingTime": 0, 
"fsSchemaCacheHits": 0, 
"fsSchemaCacheMisses": 0, 
"dbSchemaCacheHits": 0, 
"dbSchemaCacheMisses": 0, 
"envSchemaCacheHits": 16184, 
"envSchemaCacheMisses": 0, 
"fragments": [
], 
...
```

Also used `query-trace` and this is the output

```
2024-01-22 16:13:07.072 Info: /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy at 2666:37: impl:apply-search(map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), (), fn:false())
2024-01-22 16:13:07.072 Info: /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy at 2666:37: Analyzing path for search: fn:collection()
2024-01-22 16:13:07.072 Info: /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy at 2666:37: Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()
2024-01-22 16:13:07.072 Info: /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy at 2666:37: Path is fully searchable.
2024-01-22 16:13:07.072 Info: /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy at 2666:37: Gathering constraints.
2024-01-22 16:13:07.072 Info: /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy at 2666:37: Search query contributed 2 constraints: cts:and-query((cts:word-query("one", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:word-query("two", ("lang=en"), 1)), ())
2024-01-22 16:13:07.072 Info: /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy at 2666:37: Executing search.
2024-01-22 16:13:07.077 Info: /MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy at 2666:37: Selected 24292 fragments to filter
```

Examined the query-trace output in the ErrorLog.txt file and there were no steps that are unsearchable.

There are a fair few cache misses in the query meters output. The documentation then says
`cache misses indicate that the query might be able to be optimized, either by rewriting the parts of the query that have cache misses to better take advantage of the indexes or by adding indexes that the query can use.`
Because the application uses the MarkLogic Rest API, my assumption is I dont think I can optimize the query. Is there a way I can optimize this query further?
If not, then what do I need to do with the indexes so the query can use the indexes?

Assuming the cache misses are the only reason for the slow search. Any pointers from here please?

The server specs (disk space, RAM, etc) are up to date with the recommendations of MarkLogic.

**EDIT:**
The options specify `<search-option>unfiltered</search-option>` - so you are right, the search is unfiltered. There is very minor difference when re-running the search.
The disk usage for the whole of MarkLogic (installation, forests, logs, etc) is ~300G - so the document sizes are not very large.
Search result times with suggestions:

default:
PT13.944414S

return-results false:
PT0.233757S

return-results false and snippet = raw(instead of = apply):
PT0.02006S

Just with snippet = raw(instead of = apply):
PT12.063621S

So indeed looks like the most time is spent generating snippets. Is there a way to hasten that up?

These are the snippets being passed in as options:

```
<transform-results apply="snippet">
    <preferred-matches>
      <element ns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services" name="instance"/>
    </preferred-matches>
    <max-matches>1</max-matches>
    <max-snippet-chars>1000</max-snippet-chars>
    <per-match-tokens>20</per-match-tokens>
  </transform-results>

  <return-query>1</return-query>

  <!-- This controls the snippet size toggle -->
  <operator name="results">
    <state name="compact">
      <transform-results apply="snippet">
        <preferred-matches>
          <element ns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services" name="instance"/>
          <json-property>instance</json-property>
        </preferred-matches>
        <max-matches>5</max-matches>
        <max-snippet-chars>2000</max-snippet-chars>
        <per-match-tokens>100</per-match-tokens>
      </transform-results>
    </state>
    <state name="detailed">
      <transform-results apply="snippet">
        <preferred-matches>
          <element ns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services" name="instance"/>
          <json-property>instance</json-property>
        </preferred-matches>
        <max-matches>5</max-matches>
        <max-snippet-chars>2000</max-snippet-chars>
        <per-match-tokens>100</per-match-tokens>
      </transform-results>
    </state>
  </operator>
```

**EDIT2:**
Time difference in repeated running of the same function above:

```
1-PT14.17
2-PT13.96
3-PT13.96
4-PT13.91
```

With `<max-matches>1</max-matches>`
PT13.96862S

Added condition `<max-snippet-chars>200</max-snippet-chars>`
PT13.97606S

Added condition with no `per-match-tokens` tag
PT13.977932S

Added back `<per-match-tokens>10</per-match-tokens>`
PT14.173813S

Comment: 14 seconds does sound really slow for a two-word search returning 10 docs. If you repeat that search is it always ~14 seconds? Longer times for larger page size is common when filtering, but search.search executes unfiltered searches, so it shouldn't be time spent filtering.  Are the docs really large?

Comment: Wondering if it's time spent generating the snippets. Try `raw` instead of `snippet` or `return-results` false, to see where the time is being spent generating the result payload besides the search.

Comment: @MadsHansen Thanks for the comments. I have updated the question with Edits to update my findings of using `raw` etc

Comment: raw takes 12 seconds? do you have really large documents? In order to do the work for snippeting, you have to read the doc and then transform, and if it's taking the majority of that time to return the docs without any snippet/transform.....

Comment: I will have to look at the size of the documents. Are large documents a hurdle to fast searches? Am slightly confused though, because the search itself is fast when `return-results` is false. Am only guessing it does actually search with that flag. Also, if raw takes 12 seconds, then snippets isn't really the problem then, isn't it?

Comment: The search uses indexes to find relevant documents and tell you the URI. If you are returning the document, or transforming to find a snippet of useful info matching it, then it needs to read the document, which will take more time and resources than just telling you the URI and the search relevency score of the doc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The snippets are required to be returned. I have no way of reducing the size of the documents as of now. So, does that mean I have no way of reducing the time taken for search? Or, is there a recommended best practice which guides on how a document can be split - then I can propose that approach and redo the ingestion and harmonisation (though I doubt that will reduce the time taken - as there really is no change to the size of the (whole) document being read).

Comment: @happybuddha Highlighting documents to retrieve snippets can be very slow for big documents. Custom code to retrieve interesting paragraphs in a different way might be faster. For apply, your best option for now is to reduce the number of matches you are asking for. So maybe just one instead of 5. Raw will return the whole document, so you likely loose time on inserting full documents, and sending them across.

Comment: @grtjn I have added Edits2 - to report happens with your proposal. What is the maximum size of the document for optimal performance? I am a bit disappointed with this limitation - what's the point of ML then? But that ship has sailed. Is there an example/guide of how I could effectively retrieve paragraphs in a different way be faster? I disagree that this might be significantly faster because it will *eventually* take as much time as it takes for retrieving snippets and merging them with the results- but am happy to give it a go - just need to know how.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your documents? It sounds like there is a sub-optimal fit between how v1/search likes to operate, your data, and what you are trying to achieve. Some more details on what you (functionally) are trying to achieve might help too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the majority of the time is from reading the documents for the snippets.

If reading and processing 10 documents in the search results is taking 10-15 seconds, I'd be suspicious about the size of the documents and/or the capacity of the cluster.

If the searches are fast, but processing the documents is slow(er than you would like), you could try separating the search from the snippeting.

For instance, using `apply="empty-snippet"` to return the information to support the work, but then do that after the search is returned to decorate the results async?

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295

> The `apply="empty-snippet"` option returns no result node, but does return an empty search:snippet element for each search:result. The search:result wrapper element does have the information (for example, the URI and path to the node) needed to access the node and perform your own transformation on the matching search node(s), so you can write your own code outside of the Search API to process the results.

Comment: Result decoration or post transform (both options supported by v1/search) might allow you to decouple snippeting from search results. Another approach could be to return empty snippets as suggested by Mads, and then have the front-end go back per result (in parallel) to retrieve sensible snippets.